# How to display HQL result to view in grails.?

Tags: grails, groovy, hql

I have two simple classes Staff and Department and I want to list staff by department using HQL that then displayed in a view.

First of all these are Domain classes Staff and Department

```
class Staff {
 String fullName
 String dateOfBirth

 static belongsTo = [department: Department]
```

}

```
class Department {
  String department

  static hasMany = [staff: Staff]
}
```

Department has instances such as Sea, Land, Air.

Here is a StaffController.groovy (only a listbysea action for example)

```
def listbysea() {
      params.max =  Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 10, 100)

      //Query
      def staffList = Staff.executeQuery("SELECT s.fullName from Staff s join s.department d WHERE d.department = 'Sea')
      [staffInstance: staffList, staffInstanceTotal: staffList.size()]
    }
```

This is my listbysea.gsp

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <g:sortableColumn property="fullName" title="${message(code: 'staff.fullName.label', default: 'Full Name')}" />

                <g:sortableColumn property="dateOfBirth" title="${message(code: 'staff.dateOfBirth.label', default: 'Date of Birth')}" />

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <g:each in="${staffList}" status="i" var="staffInstance">
                <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">

                <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><g:link action="show" id="${staffInstance.id}"> ${fieldValue(bean: staffInstance, field: "fullName")}</g:link></td>

                <td style="vertical-align: middle;">    ${fieldValue(bean: staffInstance, field: "dateOfBirth")}</td>

                </tr>
            </g:each>
      </tbody>
   </table>
```

However, there is no data shown in the table and I am not sure whether the query indeed does not yields any results at all or it is the problem with the view.  So I am asking did I do the right thing in returning the query result to the view.? I even tried this query

```
def staffList = Staff.executeQuery("SELECT new map(s.fullName as fullName, d.department as department)\
         FROM Staff as s, Department as d \
         WHERE s.department = d HAVING s.department = ('Sea')")
```

But still no result displayed.

Appreciate any hint.

Comment: To troubleshoot, you can always put something like `println staffList` in your controller, just before the last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable name you have in your controller doesn't match what the gsp file is using.

In the controller you use `staffInstance`:

```
def staffList = Staff.executeQuery("SELECT s.fullName from Staff s join s.department d WHERE d.department = 'Sea')
[staffInstance: staffList, staffInstanceTotal: staffList.size()]
```

But in the gsp you use `staffList`:

```
<g:each in="${staffList}" status="i" var="staffInstance">
```

Try changing the controller to:

```
[staffList: staffList, staffInstanceTotal: staffList.size()]
```

Comment: Your suggestion is right but then I have errors which I think is related to HQL query because I am selecting a department which is common to both class.

Comment: Glad to hear that helped. If you feel this is the correct answer, don't forget to [click the checkmark icon next to the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Yeah this solves half part of my question which is to display back the result but I would appreciate if I get hint about HQL.

Comment: I would recommend that you open a new question specifically for the HQL part. You are much more likely to get help that way.